# Redirecting Output of ProcessBuilder in Java 5/6?

Tags: java, redirect, process, processbuilder

I am looking for a way to redirect the output of a Process / ProcessBuilder? I know that it works in Java 7 like this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectOutput();
Process process = builder.start();
```

But I need the same for Java 5/6 ... Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample code for *cmd* process on *Windows 7*, working with *Java 6*:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd" );        
Process process = processBuilder.start();
OutputStream stream = process.getOutputStream();
```

Javadoc for `getOutputStream()` method: says
*"Gets the output stream of the subprocess. Output to the stream is piped into the standard input stream of the process represented by this Process object."*

To redirect the output of a process, I think you can use `stream` object defined in the code above. You can write it to console etc.

Comment: hey deporter, many thanks for the fast reply. just using process.getInputStream() and putting it into a InputStreamReader works perfect :-)

Comment: @NicolasBaumgardt You are welcome. but in the above code i used outputstream, if inputstream is the data that you want, no problem use it. :)

Comment: hm.. my goal is to read out the stdout of the process I build and the javadoc says: "The stream obtains data piped from the standard output stream of the process represented by this Process object." the javadoc is a bit weird to me in this case...

Comment: It's a little confusing: `p.getOutputStream()` returns the stdin of `p` and `p.getInputStream()` returns the stdout of `p`. See [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Comment: This answer is incomplete as it does not redirect the output as requested. It merely get the stream reference so user can implement it on his/her own. User is expected to start a new thread to do the redirection and continue with the intended work in current thread.